# Punctuate a Blob of Text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am thinking of summarizing the audio of Youtube videos using AI, machine learning, as a Hobby project.

I am able to extract auto-generated Closed Caption text as a CLOB, given below:

> good day fellow investors I don't think I ever mentioned it but I'm
>   subscribed to almost all out of there Bloomberg Wall Street Journal
>   Morningstar and many others that I don't want to mention not to public
>   publicize them because most don't deserve my money but still if even
>   if I get a little bit from there it's good however something nice that
>   came in the email yesterday was of course Wall Street Journal and I'm
>   subscribed to their daily shot which gives a lot of slides about
>   what's going on in the economy markets etc which is always nice to
>   look at on a daily basis

But as you can see it does not have any punctuation characters at all.
I am planning to use python NLTK library, but the Sentence Tokenizer is unable to break the text into any sort of smaller chunks.

I am new to NLP (as you can guess), can anyone please point me to an article, preferably a how to guide, to "punctuate a blob of text". I am not getting much help from google search (my bad).

Please suggest a way ahead, thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here particularly well, but is a worthy question.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no NLTK/SpaCy package which can directly solve your task.

I would suggest using one of the three deep learning methods as mentioned in [this](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2016/pdf/103_Paper.pdf) LREC paper (Che et al, 2016). You have to pose your problem as a classification task, where you have to predict whether a word in the sequence is followed by a punctuation mark.

The paper itself takes a subset of the sequence, `<w(n-m) ... w(n-1), w, w(n+1), ... w(n+m)>`, to account for context, uses their word vectors, and trains on three different models, with each having 2, 3 or 4 output classes (`O`: no punctuation, `PERIOD`: periods, semi-colons, exclamation marks, `COMMA`: commas, dashes and colons, `QUESTION MARK`: q marks).

The first model uses a simple DNN, the second one a CNN, and the third one is a variation of the CNN in the second model. If you choose to go for just the periods (reducing the number of classes), the simple DNN model is reportedly providing F1-scores of ~60%.

As for the code, you could request the authors. Or since you wish to undertake it as a hobby, you could implement it from scratch yourself.